# How can I get a count of number of records in child object on parent object field?

Tags: salesforce, apex

I have an object Participant which is child of Interaction. On editing child object records the field in parent object should get incremented. The scenario is such that first time if invited is true and rsvp is null invited count on parent object should get incremented. Next for the same record if rsvp is set to yes then only rsvp field on parent object should get incremented. With my logic it is getting incremented in both invited as well as rsvp. Below is the trigger

```
Set<Id> interactionIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Participant__c erpAccount : participantList){
    interactionIds.add(erpAccount.Interaction__c);
}

List<Interaction__c> relatedInteractions =
    [Select i.Total_Number_Of_Invited_Attendees__c,
        (Select Invited__c,RSVP_Status__c,HCP__c,Interaction__c
 From  Participants__r
            WHERE Role_Group__c = 'Attendee'
                        AND (Invited__c = true
                        OR RSVP_Status__c = 'Yes'
                        OR HCP__c !=NULL))
        From Interaction__c i where id IN : interactionIds];

for(Interaction__c acc : relatedInteractions){
    //acc.Total_Number_Of_Invited_Attendees__c = 0; 

    for(Participant__c p : acc.Participants__r){
        if(p.Invited__c == true)
        {      
            if(p.RSVP_Status__c == 'Yes')
            {
                if(p.HCP__c != null)
                {
                   acc.Total_No_of_Confirmed_Customer_Attendees__c += 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    acc.Total_Number_of_Confirmed_Attendees__c += 1;                          
                }
            }
            else
            {
                acc.Total_Number_of_Invited_Attendees__c += 1;
            }
        }       
    }
}

update relatedInteractions;
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You need to update interaction object whenever Participant object is updated, currently you are updating same object.

Comment: I have the updated code